# How to know the number of repetitions, combinatory analysis

Tags: probability

> John has 20 board games. He promised to lend Richard 5 of his games. 
>   How many different ways can John do that?

I tried to do 20*19*18*17*16 and now I am supposed to divide by *something*, because having for example (A,B,C,D,E) is the same as having (E,D,C,B,A), these letter representing the games John is going to lend. Basically I have to remove the repetitions from the result.

I know the formula for this is:
$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$

My question is, how do I do that? How much are k and n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of "removing repetitions" is how we get the idea for *combinations* in the formula you stated.

The number of ways to choose $k$ objects from $n$ in which ordering is not important is $\binom{n}{k}$, read $n$ choose $k$. You may use a different notation in your class/text, but this is my preferred way.

The number of desired lendings is then $\binom{20}{5}$. Can you see what $n$ and $k$ are now?

Comment: Right, I see. Thanks